# Yii2 Eager load join by relation

Tags: php, yii2

I previously wrote a query that was lazy laoded and ordered by a relation like this:

```
Item::find()
->orderBy([Token::tableName() . '.featured' => SORT_DESC;
```

I've since changed the query to load eager but I'm having some trouble now trying to order on the relation.

```
Item::find()
->with('Token')
->orderBy(['token.featured' => SORT_DESC]);
```

I've tried that way and my calling the `Token::tableName() . featured`. But I keep getting unknown column. What's the correct way to do this eagerly for AR in Yii2?

Comment: Duplicate question with detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731512/yii2-activequery-with-not-working/26733406#26733406

Comment: @PLM57 I just up voted your q and a. Very subtle difference I had overlooked

Comment: Just saw it...thanks a lot man. I obviously ran into the same problem ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yii2 `with` does eager loading by running a separate query. To actually do the SQL join, use [`joinWith`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith%28%29-detail):

```
Item::find()
    ->joinWith('token')
    ->orderBy(['token.featured' => SORT_DESC]);
```

This should work, assuming your relation is defined in the `getToken()` method of `Item` class and its table is called `token`.