# Yii2 convert SqlDataProvider to ActiveDataProvider with left join

Tags: mysql, yii2, left-join

I have two tables: Calls, Phones

Two models: Call, Phone

and the following code:

```
$q = 'select 
      c.calling, sp.name as srcname, sp.org as srcorg, 
      c.called, dp.name as dstname, dp.org as dstorg 
      from Calls c 
      left join Phones sp on c.calling = sp.num 
      left join Phones dp on c.called = dp.num ORDER BY c.time '
$sql = Yii:$app->db->createCommand($q)
$count = $sql->queryScalar();
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
   'sql' => $q,
   'pagination' => [
      'pageSize' => 25,
    ],
   'totalCount' => $count,
]);
```

How do I convert it to ActiveDataProvider query?

```
$dataProvder = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => Call::find()->...,
'pagination' => [
      'pageSize' => 25,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few inputs for you which will also answer your question.

## Models instead of raw queries

Use [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html) to create models for your two tables. The extension is built in and you can simply open it by calling `http://yourproject.com/gii` while in debug-mode.

When you create the models it will also build your relations to the other table. You can easily customize these according to the [model-documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html) and [ActiveRecord-documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) of Yii2. The later will also show you how to specify relations [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#declaring-relations).

In your case the `Call`-model will have two `hasOne`-relations:

- `sourcePhone` referencing to the model of the phone initiating the call
- `destinationPhone` referencing to the model of the receiving phone

## The data provider and the grid view to list the calls

The initiation is now easy. Lets say you want to list all calls, you can do it as follows:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>new ActiveDataProvider(['query'=>Call::find()]),
    'columns'=>[
        'id',
        [
            'label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Source phone'),
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return $model->sourcePhone->name;
            },
        ],
        [
            'label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Destination phone'),
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return $model->destinationPhone->name;
            },
        ],
        //more columns as of your requirements...
    ],
]) ?>
```

You not only use the `ActiveDataProvider` now, you also use the common way of Yii2 to display such data (relations, etc.). Pagination and stuff can be customized on the data provider the same way as you did above.

## How to use the `join`-part with ActiveQuery

This one is easy. The actual joining of the tables will happen automatically as soon as you call the relation (lazy loaded). In the example above this will happen within here:

```
return $model->destinationPhone->name
```

This leads to another query populating the relation with the corresponsing Phone-instance. If you want this to happen together with the actual call-query, simply extend the query you provide to your ActiveDataProvdier:

```
'dataProvider'=>new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'=>Call::find()->joinWith(['sourcePhone', 'destinationPhone']),
]),
```

The `joinWith`-method tells the query to fetch the call-object together with the two relations you specify within the parameter. Make sure you read the [documentation of this method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail). I also have written an [answer to a problem I had myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731512/yii2-activequery-with-not-working/26733406#26733406) which explains it even further.

If you want to access the columns of your related objects, simply access the related object like an attribute of the call-object and then the attributes themselves. In my example above you can see how I access the `name`-attribute of the related phone-models.

Tell me if you need more information about certain parts.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! My question is how do I make the "join" query on ActiveDataProvider using ->join() or ->leftJoin() ?

Comment: and also how do I output the columns got from the join?

Comment: You're welcome! I extended my answer with the information you wanted. As it looks to me you should really read the documentation of the Model- and ActiveRecord-concept of Yii2! I linked both in the first paragraph of my answer. I guarantee you, all your questions will be gone afterwards! Otherwise just write another comment :)!

Comment: Wow! That IS an answer! Thanks for clarification. I really should read the documentation for ActiveRecord. Looked to me much easier than it is actually :)

Comment: Thanks! Well, actually it is extremely easy as you don't even have to write most of the model-code because of the Gii-generator. You simply have to double-check and fine tune the validators (`rules()`-method) and the relations within a model. But...it takes some getting used to it. Have fun reading! If you get the hang of it, it is pure pleasure to work with Yii. Just read roughly through the [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) and you'll be fine...

Comment: I actually did use the Gii to generate my models. However, I had trouble making relations between Calls and Phones as there might be Calls which phones don't match records from Phones table. That's why I have not created foreign key in Calls. And now I'm wondering if relations are going to work.